# Cant change publisher name in Universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have a couple of Universal apps in the Windows phone store that I published under a different name.  I've changed the publisher name on my account now however when I try to upload the app package, I get an error saying the publisher names don't match.

I can see what the issue is, however when I try to change the publisher name in the app manifest, it seems to get automatically switched back to the original publisher name, which results in the error.

How do I stop it switching it back to the old publisher name?

I have some other Windows phone apps that I republished successfully, however they weren't Universal apps.

Comment: Did you contact Store support?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this was just because I tried to update the apps right after changing the publisher name.  When I went back to it a few weeks later, it worked fine.